# React Native Realm Model to store array of objects?

Tags: react-native, realm

Let's say I want to store objects like this to a realm database

```
Record 1
{name:'John',attributes:{hairColor:'black',birthDate:'1990-10-01'}}

Record 2
{name:'Sara',attributes:{gender:'female',allergies:['peanuts','cocaine']}}
```

So I did something like this for my react-native project

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class ProductCategory {}
Person.schema = {
    name: 'Person',
    properties: {
        name: {type: 'string'},
        attributes: {type: 'list',objectType:'json'},
    }
};

Realm.open({schema: [Person]});
```

Running this code in my react-native application gives the error message:

> Warning encountered 1 time. Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection
>   (id:0): Error: Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'Person.attributes'of type 'array' has unknown object type 'json'

How do I define attributes to be an array?

Comment: Considering those objects you have are dynamically typed with dynamic keys, you might want to just save 'em as a JSON string

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if attributes were just an array of integers, should I also just stringify it as well?

Comment: Well `attributes` seems to be like literally everything, and Realm expects a typed schema.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce whoops, let me clarify my question. I plan to create another property called lotteryNumbers and it will take values like [12,443,342,5] or [43,32,2] .  In the past, I got a similar error as above, even though I set schema to be `{name:'Person',properties:{name:{type:'string'},lotteyNumbers:{type:'list',objectType:'integer'}}}`.  I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out the realm documentation on how to save an array of integers, and in general the acceptable values for objectType.

Comment: `objectType` allows only objects that are part of the Realm schema. But Realm-JS 2.0.0-RC18 (latest 2.x at the moment) already seems to support array of primitives, the Realm-JS 1.x does not.

Comment: To me it seems that in 2.x you need to change `list: {type: 'list', objectType: 'PersonObject'},` to `list: 'PersonObject[]',` and array of primitives like `doubleArrayCol: 'double[]',`or `optDateArrayCol:   'date?[]',` according to https://github.com/realm/realm-js/commit/9a31febc4cb6862e7b514603f64cb64130655c92#diff-84c5c8050ffd66f9226126003eb882b1R94

Answer (score 2):

**What I understood from the question:**

You would like to save records of people and their corresponding attributes; so when you query, say, John, you can later do `john.attributes.hairColor` and get `black`

*What I didn't understand is why `attributes` is `type: 'list'` when it seems to be an object. (Perhaps you meant it to be an array of objects?) Contrast it with `allergies` which is clearly an array.*

**How I would create the schema** (I can't run the code right now, so please verify and let me know if it worked) :

```
class Attributes {}
Attributes.schema = {
  name: "Attributes",
  properties: {
    hairColor: "string?", // ? = optional
    birthDate: "date?",
    gender: "string?",
    allergies: "string?[]", // [] = list or array
  }
}

class Person {}
Person.schema = {
  name: "person",
  properties: {
    name: "string",
    attributes: "Attributes", // Nested schema
  }
}
```

---

In the comments, you mention you'd like to create another property `lotteryNumbers` which is an array of numbers. I would implement it like this inside `Person.schema.properties`-

```
properties: {
  ...
  lotteryNumbers: "int[]" // Array of integers
}
```

Please let me know if I made any mistakes; I am learning as well, that is how I reached here :p